# Chosen select with jQuery validation error placement

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-chosen

I have managed to successfully validate the Chosen plugin select form. However I am having issues changing the placement of the error. It always appears on top of the  element.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$('#form-scriptolution-soft-post-image').on('submit', function() {$('.chzn-done').valid();
});
</script>

<div class="field">
<label>
<h4>{$lang260}<span> *</span></h4>                        
</label>
<select name="CID" id="CID" required style="width:389px; height: 30px;" data-    placeholder="Choose..." >
<option value=""></option>
{section name=i loop=$c}                  
<option value="{$c[i].CID}">{$c[i].cname}</option>
{/section}
</select>                        
<p class="info">some text</p>
</div>
```

I want the error to appear in the

element at the place of "some text"

I have been trying to use the following, which works with all of my other form elements:

```
errorElement: 'p',
errorClass: 'error',
errorContainer: ".field p"
```

Any ideas will be much appreciated

I was able to resolve the issue. Here is how my code looks now:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#form-scriptolution-soft-post-image').validate(
{
ignore: "",
rules: {
image: {
required: true
},
CID: {
required: true
},
title: {
required: true
},
tags: {
required: true
},
},
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
$('.field p').html(error);

},
});
});
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
required: "This is a required field.",
});
// end document.ready
</script> 

<div class="field">
<label>
<h4>{$lang260}<span> *</span></h4>                        
</label>
<select name="CID" id="CID" required style="width:389px; height: 30px;" data-       placeholder="Choose..." >
<option value=""></option>
{section name=i loop=$c}                  
<option value="{$c[i].CID}">{$c[i].cname}</option>
{/section}
</select>                        
<p class="info">some text</p>
</div>
```

What I did was to add `ignore: "",` in the validation code so that the validation plugin does NOT ignore hidden fields. The Chosen plugin actually hides the default select field. I was able to output the error at the place of the `p` element I by adding the following `errorPlacement` option:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
$('.field p').html(error);
```

Everything now works as expected.
Thanks!

Comment: It came out that another validation function I am using for the same form messes up the situation. I was able to validate the chosen select by telling the validation plugin not to ignore hidden fileds. What I want to achieve now is that the error should be shown in the `<p class="info">` element which I have after each input field. It does not seem to work correctly using the `errorContainer` option I have above.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the position for the error placement using its function. Here is an example:

```
    $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
         operations:
        {
            required: true
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr("name") == "operations") {
            error.insertAfter("#operations_chosen");
        }else{
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply test the results of `valid()` and use a JQuery selector to change the text yourself.

```
<script>
  $('#form-scriptolution-soft-post-image').on('submit', function() {
    if(!$('.chzn-done').valid()){
      $('.field p').html('You must select a choice!');
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. The code does change the "some text" to "You must select a choice", however the same error appears at the top of the select box as well. So actually two errors are being generated.

Comment: Hmm...are you using any other javascript besides ```JQuery Validation plugin```? Where are you setting ```errorElement: 'p'``` at?